# Backbone Menu Not Sorting

Tags: javascript, sorting, backbone.js, backbone-views, comparator

I'm having trouble getting a Backbone collection to sort properly. I inherited the project, so there may be some shenanigans someplace else, but I want to rule out any syntax error on my part.

The project uses a JSON file to handle the data:

```
"classifications": [
            {
                "name": "1 Bedroom",
                "alias": "1BR",
                "id": "1BR",
                "menu_desc": "Residences"
            },
            {
                "name": "2 Bedroom",
                "alias": "2BR",
                "id": "2BR",
                "menu_desc": "Residences"
            },
            {
                "name": "3 Bedroom",
                "alias": "3BR",
                "id": "3BR",
                "menu_desc": "Residences"
            },
            {
                "name": "4 Bedroom",
                "alias": "4BR",
                "id": "4BR",
                "menu_desc": "Residences"
            },
            {
                "name": "Common Areas",
                "alias": "Common",
                "id": "Common",
                "menu_desc": "Resident Amenities"
            }
        ]
```

Previously, there were no one-bedroom units, and the order in which it rendered was this:

[image: original order]

I added the one-bedroom classification, and suddenly the order was this:

[image: incorrect order]

I did some digging and found documentation about the comparator property, but it only seems to apply to collections. This project doesn't use a collection for the classifications. It does for the submenu items (which floor the units are on, etc.), but not the main menu:

```
    var MenuClassificationListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    id: "classification_accordion",
    template: _.template( "<% var classifications = this.options.classifications; _.each(this.collection.attributes, function(v,k) { %>"+
                                        "<h3 class='<%= k %>'><%= classifications.get(k).get('name') %>"+
                                        "<p><%=classifications.get(k).get('menu_desc')%></p></h3>"+
                                        "<% var model = new MenuClassificationList(v); var view = new MenuClassificationItemView({collection:model, classification:k}); %>"+
                                        "<% print(view.render().el.outerHTML); %>"+
                                "<% }); "+
                            "%>"),
    render: function(){
        //console.log(this.options.classifications);
        //console.log(this.collection.attributes);
        //alert(1);
        this.$el.html(this.template());
        return this;

    }

});
```

How do I incorporate the comparator?

Thanks,

ty

Answer (score 1):

One way could be to define a collection for the classifications, same way they are defined for the other items you mention:

```
var Classifications = Backbone.Collections.extend({ // etc. etc.
```

That way you can add the comparator and it will always be sorted.

Another way is to sort (http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy) the array in the `initialize` function in your view:

```
initialize: function(options) { // sorry don't remember the exact syntax for the parameters passed in, but I believe options is what you need
    this.options.sortedclassifications = _sortBy(options.classifications, function (c) { return parseInt(c.id); }); // or any other sorting logic
}
```

Then in the `template` use the sorted classifications:

```
template: _.template( "<% var classifications = this.options.sortedclassifications; _.each(this.collection.attributes, function(v,k) { %>" + // etc. etc.
```

This should give you what you need. However, if I may add a personal opinion, I would go through the effort of defining a Collection for the classifications and a model for the single classification. Moreover, I would keep the `MenuClassificationListView` but also create a `MenuClassificationView` that will hold the single classification template.

In this way you are able to compose views, change rendering of the single classification without changing the list and scope the events to the inner views (so clicking on a single classification is handled by the single classification view). It makes everything cleaner, more composable and readable, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

_.sortBy does not need to be used as Backbone collections already come with built in functionality for sorting.

See: http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-comparator

Example:

```
var SortedCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    comparator: 'key'
});

var mySortedCollection = new SortedCollection([{a:5, key:2}, {key:1}]);

console.log( mySortedCollection.toJSON() );
// [{key:1}, {a:5, key:2}]
```

However, the collection will not be automatically re-sorted when changing the key attribute. See:

```
mySortedCollection.at(0).set( 'key', 3 );

console.log( mySortedCollection.toJSON() );
// [{key:3}, {a:5, key:2}]
```

You have multiple options to solve this problem: you can manually call `mySortedCollection.sort()` or you can initialize the collection by binding its `change:key` event to re-sort the collection. The `change:key` event is triggered by the model whose key attribute is changed. This event is automatically propagated to the collection.

```
var AutoSortedCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    comparator: 'key',
    initialize: function() {
        this.listenTo( this, 'change:key', this.sort );
    }
});
```

In addition, I suggest removing functionality from the templates. It is easy to debug Backbone Views, but it gets harder to read the stack trace as you move functionality inside the template string. You also enforce proper separation of concerns by using your Backbone View for preparing all data for presentation and your template should just display it.

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    //...
    serializeData: function() {
       return { 
           classifications: this.collection.toJSON(),
           keys: this.collection.length > 0 ? this.collection.at(0).keys() : [] 
       }; // already sorted
    } 
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template( this.serializeData() ));
    }
});
```

Your template string becomes much easier to read: you can directly use the variables `classifications` and `keys`, iterate on them with `_.each` and simply reference to values without having to deal with the Collection syntax.